# Getting a noClassDefFound error whilst running a class file (from cmd) that references another class file in the same package/direcory

Tags: java, cmd, noclassdeffounderror

I'm new to Java programming, so hear me out!
I write all my programs with JEdit and Notepad++ and compile and run them with the windows command line. (cd -directory- javac file.java java file etc...)
However, I've never been able to run a program file with multiple class files.
Here's the program I've been trying to test:

```
package JavaTests;

public class file1{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Test test = new Test("Hello");
        Test test2 = new Test("Good");
        test.say(true);
        test.newln();
        test2.say(false);
        System.out.println(test2.getMessage());
        test2.setMessage("GoodBye");
        test2.say(true);
    }
}
```

and the 'Test' class:

```
package JavaTests;

public class Test{
    private String message;
    public Test(){
        message = "I have nothing to say.";
    }
    public Test(String thingToSay){
        message = thingToSay;
    }
    void say(boolean newLn){
        if(newLn){
            System.out.println(message);
        }else{
            System.out.print(message);
        }
    }
    void setMessage(String newMessage){
        message = newMessage;
    }
    String getMessage(){
        return message;
    }
    void newln(){
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The Java files are in the folder `...\Desktop\JavaTests\`
so I enter

```
cd ...\Desktop\JavaTests
javac file1.java Test.java
java file1
```

The java files compile correctly and the class files appear in the JavaTests folder, but when I try to run file1:

```
C:\...\Desktop\JavaTests>java file1
Error: Could not find or load main class file1
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: JavaTests/file1 (wrong name: file1)
```

and If I try `java JavaTests.file1`:

```
C:\...\Desktop\JavaTests>java JavaTests.file1
Error: Could not find or load main class JavaTests.file1
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: JavaTests.file1
```

The Files definitely exist, and I double-checked the classpath.
Most other questions were instances of 'exception in the thread Main'. I can't figure out what's wrong. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java, the norm is to name your class with a Capital first letter. So instead of file1, name it File1 
e.g. 
      `public class File1 {`

And save it with the same name i.e. `File1.java` .
Since you are keeping all the classes in the same package, write all classes in the same package in the same file and save it in the name of the driver class (the class with the main method which is File1.java). Then compile it i.e.

`javac File1.java`

After compilation, you would notice the  generated classes i.e. File1.class and Test.class.
Then you can run your program by executing the driver class i.e. 
      java File1

edit :  Here's some detail ,

1. Open your File1.java ,
2. make sure your driver class is File1 .
3. copy the contents of Test class and paste it on File1.java just after the driver declaration.

e.g.

`public  class File1 {`
 `//codes here`
  `}`

`class Test {`
  `//codes here`
 `}`

4. Save it

I also noticed just now that your package name starts with a capital letter. The norm is that package names SHOULD NOT contain Capital letters. So you can rename the package name to contain only small letters.

Also make sure, this file (File1.java ) contains in folder/directory of its own.
Then compile it.

Comment: I tried renaming the driver file to 'File1', but still got the error. Also, by "write all classes in the same package in the same file" did you mean in in the same java file? Because you can only have one public class per source file.